# add elements to a panel on the runtime in java

Tags: java, swing, layout, constructor, jpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dynamically add JLabels to JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030124/how-to-dynamically-add-jlabels-to-jpanel)

I have a created a panel and using a gridlayout for it.

> ```
> public pnlFriends() {
>     initComponents();
>     this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
>    // showFriends();
>
> }
>
> private void formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
>     showFriends();
>     System.out.print("comp");
> }
>
>    private void showFriends()
>    {
>     //Integer id = NewMain.network.getEdges().get(Main.uuid).getDegree();
>     for(int i = 0;i < 10 ;i++)
>     {
>
>         String name = "as";
>         String occupation ="adf";
>         String place = "asdf";
>         Integer connections = 5;
>         this.add(displayMiniProfile(name,occupation,place,connections));
>     }
> }
> ```

where the `displayMiniProfile` return a JPanel.

Now when I have this function called in the constructor of the parent JPanel, it works and I can add MiniProfile JPanel.

But when I am calling this function in the response of `componentshown` event it doesn't show anything.

**WHY ?**

And how can I achieve the same ?

Comment: You failed to pray to great coding gods in the sky?...Without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) everything would be guess work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is shown because the `JPanel` still has not been validated after the new panel has been added. You will need to call

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

after calling

```
this.add(displayMiniProfile(name,occupation,place,connections));
```

Comment: it worked. Just wanted to ask one more thing.Will repaint work ?

Comment: No, you need `revalidate` here, `repaint` won't do the validation necessary to account for the newly added panel :)

Comment: @Reimeus it would actually be `revalidate()` and  `repaint()` to reflect the changes, calling only `revalidate` wont wok in some cases.

Comment: In this case, `repaint()` not strictly needed but have added it  to answer as "best practice" for any future readers.