# Not able to Display Image on JLabel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, imageicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dynamically add JLabels to JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030124/how-to-dynamically-add-jlabels-to-jpanel)

```
private void jXHyperlink1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
NewClass n=new NewClass();
n.myf();
try{
    ImageIcon ic=new ImageIcon("tmp/Photo0087.jpg");
    ll=new JLabel(ic,JLabel.CENTER);
    jPanel6.add(ll);
    repaint();
}catch(Exception x){
    System.out.println(x.getMessage());
   }
    }
```

`myf()` method opens up a `JFileChooser` in which on Pressing Open button of `JFileChooser` the image file gets copied to a temporary folder tmp (I copied Photo0087.jpg).

I am trying to display the file **Photo0087.jpg** on a `JLabel` for which i wrote the above code but its not working.

Comment: We need additional code and additional information about this problem. In particular: how did you copy the file? are you sure your code to copy a file is correct? are you sure that the "tmp" folder is in the same folder where your program is?

Comment: Why are you dynamically adding the label as opposed to adding it at start-up & setting the icon (e.g as seen in [`ImageViewer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13463684/418556)) in the mouse event method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to revalidate the `JPanel` after adding the new `JLabel`:

```
jPanel6.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass Absolute image path like this `C:\\folder\\folder2\\image.jpg`

or try this `ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image location"))`